# Нарисовать координатную плоскость с сеткой(с возможностью масштабирования)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, функции

Всем привет!
Задача такая:
Нужно нарисовать 4 графика по типу (x-cos(x)), и сделать 2 способами , через chart (я уже сделал) и без chart . 
Я предполагаю что нужно использовать picturebox,но как. **ВАЖНЫЙ фактор** , заключается в том что нужно реализовать масштабирование координатной сетки , масштаб выбирает пользователь. 
Помогите реализовать . Спасибо!

Comment: Рисуете сетку и графики с помощью методов класса Graphics. Масштаб меняете вызовом [Graphics.ScaleTransform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.scaletransform?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Это WPF или в Winforms Это тоже есть ?

Comment: В метках стоит WinForms. Неужто я стану предлагать что-то из другого фреймворка? В документации к классу [Graphics](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics?view=netframework-4.8) прямо написано, где он используется. А главное, проверить всё самому - одна минута.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот простенький пример рисования с помощью методова класса [Graphics](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics?view=netframework-4.8).

Рисуется синусоида.
С помощью NumericUpDown можно менять масштаб (мышкой или клавишами вверх/вниз).

Методом [TranslateTransform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.translatetransform?view=netframework-4.8) сдвигаем ось координат (по умолчанию она будет в левом верхнем углу).
Методом [ScaleTransform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.scaletransform?view=netframework-4.8) меняем масштаб.
Думаю, из кода всё понятно.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private float scale = 1;
        NumericUpDown numericUpDown;
        PictureBox pictureBox;

        public Form1()
        {
            Size = new Size(400, 400);

            pictureBox = new PictureBox
            {
                Parent = this,
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                Size = new Size(300, 300)
            };
            pictureBox.Paint += PictureBox_Paint;

            numericUpDown = new NumericUpDown
            {
                Parent = this,
                Minimum = 1,
                Maximum = 10,
                DecimalPlaces = 1,
                Increment = 0.1m,
                Top = pictureBox.Bottom + 20
            };
            numericUpDown.ValueChanged += NumericUpDown_ValueChanged;
        }

        private void PictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(100, 100);
            e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

            var prev = new PointF(0, (float)Math.Sin(0));

            for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++)
            {
                var y = Math.Sin(x);
                var curr = new PointF(x, (float)y);
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, prev, curr);
                prev = curr;
            }
        }

        private void NumericUpDown_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            scale = (float)numericUpDown.Value;
            pictureBox.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```